# Separate folders into subfolders according to numbering in bash

Tags: bash

I have the following directory tree:

```
1_loc
2_buzdfg
4_foodga
5_bardfg
6_loc
8_buzass
9_foossd
12_bardaf
```

There may be numbers missing in the folder ordering.

I want to separate these folders into subfolders according to their numbers, so that all folders with a number smaller than 6 (before the second `_loc` folder) would go to `folder1` and all folders with a number equal or greater than 6 with go to `folder2`.

I can solve the problem very easily using the mouse, of course, but I wanted a suggestion of how to do this automatically from the terminal.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while read -r line; do
    # Regex match the beginning of the string for a character between 1 and 5 - change this as you'd please to any regex
    FOLDERNUMBER=""
    [[ "$line" ~= "^[1-5]" ]] && FOLDERNUMBER="1" || FOLDERNUMBER="2"

    # So FOLDERPATH = "./folder1", if FOLDERNUMBER=1
    FOLDERPATH="./folder$FOLDERNUMBER"

    # Check folder exists, if not create it
    [[ ! -d "$FOLDERPATH" ]] && mkdir "$FOLDERPATH"

    # Finally, move the file to FOLDERPATH
    mv "$line" "$FOLDERPATH/$(basename $line)"
done < <(find . -type f)
# This iterates through each line of the command in the brackets - in this case, each file path from the `find` command.
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the solution is to loop through the files and check the number before the first `_`.

Firstly, let's check how to get the number before `_`:

```
$ d="1_loc_b"
$ echo "${d%%_*}"
1
```

OK, so this works. Then, let's loop:

```
for file in *
do
     echo "$file"
     (( ${file%%_*} > 5)) && echo "moving to dir2/" || echo "moving to dir1/"
done
```

Comment: Why don't I need to use `$` before `(( ${file%%_*} > 5))`? Or, why do I only need to use `$` when I want to echo the result?

Comment: @DanielG because this uses the [`(( ... ))` conditional construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs).

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `folder1` and `folder2` exists in the same directory, I will do it like this:

```
for d in *_*; do # to avoid folder1 and folder2
    # check if the first field seperated by _ is less than 5 
    if ((`echo $d | cut -d"_" -f1` < 6)); then 
         mv $d folder1/$d; 
    else 
         mv $d folder2/$d; 
    fi; 
done
```

(more about [`cut`](http://www.computerhope.com/unix/ucut.htm))

Answer (score 1):

You can go to the current directory and run these simple commands:

```
mv {1,2,3,4}_* folder1/
mv {5,6,7,8}_* folder2/
```

This assumes no other files/directory starting with these prefixes (i.e. 1-8).

Answer (score 1):

Another pure `bash`, parameter-expansion solution:-

```
#!/bin/bash

# 'find' returns folders having a '_' in their names, the flag -print0 option to 
#  preserve special characters in names.

#  the folders are names as './1_folder', './2_folder', bash magic is done
#  to remove those special characters.

# '-v' flag in 'mv' for verbose action

while IFS= read -r -d '' folder; do

    folderName="${folder%_*}"     # To strip the characters after the '_'
    finalName="${folderName##*/}" # To strip the everything before '/'

    ((finalName > 5)) && mv -v "$folder" folder1 || mv -v "$folder" folder2

done < <(find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -name "*_*" -type d -print0)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create the a script with the following code and when you run it, the folders will be moved as desired..

```
#seperate the folders into 2 folders
#this is a generic solution for any folder that start with a number
#!/bin/bash
for file in *
do
prefix=`echo $file | awk 'BEGIN{FS="_"};{print $1}'`

if [[ $prefix != ?(-)+([0-9]) ]]
then continue
fi

if [ $prefix -le 4 ]
then mv "$file" folder1

elif [ $prefix -ge 5 ]
then mv "$file" folder2

fi

done
```